# Sort by regular expressions

Tags: regular-expression, sort

I've got a set of POSIX regular expressions*

```
^BEGIN:VCARD\r$
^VERSION[^A-Z]
^FN[^A-Z]
^N[^A-Z]
^NICKNAME[^A-Z]
^EMAIL[^A-Z]
^X-\([A-Z-]*\)
^TEL[^A-Z]
^ADR[^A-Z]
^ORG[^A-Z]
^TITLE[^A-Z]
^BDAY[^A-Z]
^URL[^A-Z]
^ROLE[^A-Z]
^NOTE[^A-Z]
^END:VCARD\r$
```

and a file with lines which each match one of the regular expressions:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
N:Doe;Jane;;Ms;
URL:http://janedoe.com/
EMAIL:jdoe@example.org
EMAIL:jane.doe@janedoe.com
BDAY:1970-01-01
X-JABBER:jane.doe@example.org
X-ICQ:1234567890
END:VCARD
```

I'd like to sort these lines according to

1. the line number of the regex match (so that lines starting with FN comes before lines starting with N),
2. the match group (so that X-ABC comes before X-DEF)

Ideally, the other parts of the lines should not be sorted (so the sequence of lines which start with EMAIL should be left alone). The expected result should therefore be:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
N:Doe;Jane;;Ms;
EMAIL:jdoe@example.org
EMAIL:jane.doe@janedoe.com
X-ICQ:1234567890
X-JABBER:jane.doe@example.org
BDAY:1970-01-01
URL:http://janedoe.com/
END:VCARD
```

Is there an existing tool to do this?

Edit: [Resulting implementation](https://github.com/l0b0/vcard/blob/master/sort-lines.sh) based on [Lars Rohrbach's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/40473/3645).

* This is the sequence of vCard properties in a Gmail contacts export file.

Comment: With just about any tool, you'll likely have a problem with the unmatched 'remaining' lines since there will be nothing relative to indicate their position.  In your example, you are not keeping their position relative to the original (which should be after `X-ICQ`) or relative to the lines preceding or succeeding being sorted. Otherwise, the lines would be after `URL` or before `BDAY`.

Comment: This sounds a bit like meta-regex-golf... https://xkcd.com/1313/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual `sort` command doesn't provide an included way to specify your specific "dictionary", and while the `grep` command allows you to provide a file of regular expressions, it won't change the order of the output.  But you can put both together in a simple `foreach` loop -- here's an example that works in the bash shell:

```
for i in `cat fileofregexp`; do grep "$i" myinputfile; done
```

This takes each regexp line from your file of regular expressions one by one, and outputs any match from your inputfile, so the resulting output will be sorted by your regexp order.  Note that any lines in your inputfile that don't match at all will not make it to the output.

**Addendum:** As requested, here's a version using a `while` loop:

```
while IFS= read -r i; do grep "$i" myinputfile; done  < fileofregexp
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly how you framed it, but given your actual purpose it would be simpler to grab the part before the colon and sort by that. Here's a Perl script which accumulates lines from separate sort keys in separate array entries, and flushes a vcard when it reaches the end.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -n
BEGIN {
    @headers = qw(BEGIN VERSION FN N NICKNAME EMAIL X- TEL ADR ORG TITLE BDAY URL ROLE NOTE END);
    for $h (@headers) { $data{$h} = ""; }
}
if (/^([^:]+):/) {
    $data{exists $data{$1} ? $1 : "X-"} .= $_;
    if ($1 eq 'END') {
        for $h (@headers) { print $data{$h}; $data{$h} = ""; }
    }
} else {
    print;
}
```

And if you really want the full regexp flexibility, iterate over regexps instead of looking up a key in a hash.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -n
BEGIN {
    @regexps = qw(^BEGIN:VCARD\r$ ^VERSION[^A-Z] ^FN[^A-Z] ^N[^A-Z] ... ^END:VCARD\r$);
    for $r (@regexps) { $data{$r} = ""; }
}
for $r (@regexps) {
    next unless $_ =~ $r;
    $data{$r} .= $_;
    last;
}
if ($_ =~ $regexps[@regexps-1]) {
    for $r (@regexps) { print "++", $data{$r}; $data{$r} = ""; }
}
```